# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Недопустимое имя объекта "..."

Tags: c#, api, entity-framework, rest

Возникает исключение Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Недопустимое имя объекта "..." в:
Project > Repository > CatalogRepository ->

```
public ICollection<Catalog> GetCatalogs()
{
    return _context.Catalogs.ToList();
}
```

В чем может быть ошибка?

Репозиторий: https://github.com/artzse/ManagementCompanyAPI/tree/main/ManagementCompanyAPI

Comment: Какие данные есть в таблице Catalogs? Какие поля есть в таблице Catalogs? Просьба описать не то, что Вы описали в коде, а данные из MsSQL